# What counts as explosive damage?

Tags: the-division-2

Let's say I've got the **Destructive** passive talent that increases my explosive damage by 20%.

- Does this increase the damage dealt to enemies when I shoot a canister?
- Does this increase the damage dealt to enemies when I shoot their explosive weak points or RC explosive cars?

Overall, does this increase the explosive damage I *cause* or the explosive damage *produced* by me?

Comment: Won't answer since I'm not 100% sure. But from my understanding and from what I have seen, it's explosive damage caused by you. E.g grenades and skills with explosive damage.

Comment: Dang. I was really hoping that the talent (I forget it's name) that gives +50% explosive damage after killing an enemy skill was secretly good. If I didn't just get the same talents over and over again, I'd test it myself.

Comment: I could be wrong, but that's my understanding of it